# Is there any way to send SMS without OLE Automation?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2016

We use OLE Automation methods such as SP_OAmethod, Sp_Oacreate, etc.. to send SMS to users from SQL Server. I wish to stop use OLE Automation. Is there any alternate way to send SMS?

Comment: Add what you've researched and tried to your question or your question will likely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to send SMS without OLE Automation?

You can write your own C# solution using [CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/common-language-runtime-integration-overview?view=sql-server-ver16) and deploy it to SQL Server, such as a CLR procedure. Doing so will allow you to (either directly or indirectly via web service calls) leverage other already built frameworks for sending out SMS messages.

CLR is a rather standard way to implement logic that is outside the scope of T-SQL, that can be executed within SQL Server via T-SQL code, stored within T-SQL-like objects.

Comment: But why do it from SQL Server at all? Why not do it from some C# client app, or from a Powershell script?

Comment: @Charlieface Good questions for OP eh? 

Comment: @J.D.  Thank you for your Solution, Well Actually I'm a DBA, I am not sure how C# developers use sp_OAmethod to send SMS.  I'll inform this to C# Developers to change their code.

Comment: @dbajayy "*I am not sure how C# developers use sp_OAmethod to send SMS.*" - They don't. Instead, they can send SMS messages in C# through a multitude of other methods, that are easier and more resilient to code with. But depending on how it's coded, the C# code can essentially be deployed as its own stored procedure on SQL Server, if that's where you need to execute the code from.